# In java how to choose closest matching string

Tags: java, string, replace

I am having JSON like this.

```
{
    "mappingData": {
        "input.data.DT": "Integer",
        "input.data.DTF": "STRING"
    }
}
```

And nested function like this.

```
Functions.test2(Functions.test1(Functions.test3(input.data.DTF),input.data.DT,"string","int"),input.data.DTF)
```

Now I want to replace the keys in mappingdata json or map key with value in the respective position of function. How I can do this as if I use contains and replace and it won't replace as mappingData key input.data.DTF which is similar to input.data.DT So, replace will be inconsistant.
How can I do this.

EXPECTED RESULT:

```
Functions.test2(Functions.test1(Functions.test3(STRING),Functions.test2(Functions.test1(Functions.test3(STRING),Integer,"string","int"),STRING),"string","int"),STRING)
```

JAVA code:

```
Map<String, String> mapData = (Map<String, String>) data.get("mappingData");
System.err.println("mapData===>" + mapData);
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
  try {
    String function = entry.getValue();
    //System.out.println("function===="+function);
    if (function.contains("Functions")) {
      for (Entry<String, String> entry1 : mapData.entrySet()) {
        if (function.contains(entry1.getKey())) {
          function = function.replace(entry1.getKey(), entry1.getValue());
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```